# PHP parse a string to make a date?

Tags: php, datetime

Ok i have this in my mysql database in a datetime field

```
2011-12-30 14:07:46
```

i need using php to use this format

```
December 30, 2011, 2:07 pm
```

so i used this

```
date("F j, Y, g:i a", $system['date_added']);
```

but the outcome was this error

```
A non well formed numeric value encountered in quote.php on line 56
```

and this outcome

```
December 31, 1969, 4:33 pm
```

I know there is

```
print_r(date_parse($system['date_added']));
```

but i get an array....any ideas on an easy way to address this

Comment: SO is so popular that people dont go to forum, irc, list or even *google*

Answer (score 3):

The second param of the date should be the unix timestamp, which you can get using strtotime which gets string representation of a date and converts it to unix timestamp:

```
date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($system['date_added']));
```

Comment: correct answer, but how should anyone learn from this without even a tiny piece of explanation?

Comment: strtotime() converts an english formatted time string to an UNIX-Timestamp. That you can convert to any time format you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime).

```
date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($system['date_added']));
```

Answer (score 2):

The `date()`'s second argument is a UNIX timestamp, you're giving it *2011-12-30 14:07:46* which is not.

There are two ways to handle this. Either one will work.

- Pull out the date as a UNIX timestamp.

  ```
  SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`field`) FROM ...
  ```
- Parse the date using `strtotime()`.

  ```
  $timestamp = strtotime($system['date_added']);
  date("F j, Y, g:i a", $timestamp);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your db-date with strtotime()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php